# Python Selenium finding element

Tags: python, selenium

I need your help for a strange  problem.
I am using Selenium library and I have problem with this instruction:

```
driver.find_element_by_name('longitude')
```

Sometimes it works and I can find the element with the name **longitude** and sometimes not even if nothing changes in the web page.

Comment: You should be using either `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div')` or `driver.find_element_by_id('longitude')`. Is `driver.find_element_by_name()` even a valid method? Are you using the same code every time?

Comment: may be you need to wait for the element to be appeared/displayed

Comment: Yes I am using the same code every time. What is stranger is when the code deosn't work I just rewrite this instruction and it works again.

Comment: By the the way I  tried all type of find.element function and by_name is the only one that works.

Answer (score 0):

Use wait method before finding the element:-
eg.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"element")))
```

Comment: Sorry but I have this message: webDriverwait is not defined

Comment: have you imported these two librarylibraries?                                     
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  and     
                                                                                                        
               from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

Comment: you are wright i didn't import them but i usualy use import time and time.sleep() it is more simple

Answer (score 0):

use `time.sleep(seconds)` to load the page then after you can find the web element
sometimes if the page is not loaded it can throw like **web element** is not available 
so use `time.sleep()`

Comment: Yes I use time.sleep to have enough time to make the page loaded. To be more clear: when it is not working any more, the only thing that I to do to make it work again is to rewrite the instruction in code file nothing else which I find it too strange

Comment: Here is it: http://www.soda-pro.com/fr/web-services/meteo-data/gfs-forecasts                   it's a weather website.

Comment: Have you tried to get to the url yet and make some test?

Answer (score 0):

You can implicit wait for that :

Something like :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
driver.find_element_by_name('longitude')
```

**OR**

**Explicit wait** :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,"longitude")))
```

For this you have to import these :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Please Note that you should not be mixing **implicit wait** with **explicit wait** , doing so can cause **unpredictable** **wait** time out.